# find duplicate address from file containing addresses without specific delemiter

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

Using Linux,

1. I want to sort and identify duplicate addresses from the file which contains addresses `(one address in one single line)` but no specific `delimiter`.
2. Redirect list of each duplicate address in a file with filename as the duplicate address itself.

I tried all using `grep -i "AX.*BY.*CZ"` from the address `criteria, sed, awk, agrep`

but the problem is that every time it searches only the presence of string in the file but not in the sequential way like `AX and then BY and then CZ`. That's why lot of anomaly in the output.

Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: kindly please insert INPUT/OUTPUT in order to help you.

Comment: please insert a small sample of your input and expected output into your question.  Linking to a google drive document (or other external resource) is **NOT** the same as inserting it into your question - it is problematic for most of the same reasons that posting images is problematic (see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: You should anonymise your list too - that .csv file you posted looks like it contains the addresses for about 20,000 people and businesses.  you've just compromised their privacy and helped to enable identify theft.

Comment: Are the lines with the same address identical or can the delimiter be different?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your `address-list.csv` file, this appears to be a case of [Garbage In, Garbage Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

I doubt if you can do what you want with `grep` or `sed`.  In fact, I doubt if there's any tool or scripting language that you can use.

You may be able to do something vaguely useful with `awk` or `perl` or similarly capable language but there doesn't even seem to be a consistent format to the addresses - most have what looks like a six-digit postal code, but not all lines do.  Many seem to have the city name and the country as the 2nd-last and last fields (e.g. "Kolkata INDIA") but some skip the country, some have the city name before the postal code, some have a town name followed by the street address, and some have neither city nor country. Some have the personal/family/business name before the street address, some have it after, some don't have a name.

In short, the entire file is a mess that can't be processed automatically without a huge set of street names, city/town/suburb names, postal codes, state names, etc....and even if you had such a list, trying to match all of those against substrings of each line would be horrendously complex.

Processing this requires intelligence (human or artificial), not a regular expression or other formula.

This is the problem with trying to process free-form text that doesn't even pretend to have any structure.  With some of the oddities in the file, I'd say that this .csv file goes way beyond merely free-form and into "bizarre-form".

And this is why you never let users enter addresses in free-form text fields.  You give them a standard set of fields for the various parts that make up an address - name, street number, street name, suburb, city, post code, country, etc.  Some users will still manage to screw it up somehow but the vast majority of your data will be in a usable form...and the remainder can either be fixed by hand or just discarded.

IMO, your best option is to manually edit it with a text editor into some standardised form that can be easily processed with line-oriented tools like `grep`.  `vi` is particularly good at such repetitive editing tasks - modal editors excel at such tasks, and a skilled person can finish in a tiny fraction of the time that it would take using a simple, modeless editor like `nano`.

I would suggest something like:

```
name:street address:postal code:city:country:comments
```

NOTE: there aren't many `:` characters in the .csv file and those that are there can be removed or replaced with `.` characters.  Also, `country` may be optional (it seems to be a list of entirely Indian addresses) but it doesn't hurt to have it - your code could default to "India" if the country field is empty.

Alternatively, maybe you can try to find an address list that isn't garbage...but i guess you're trying to create one because this is all you have.

Comment: +1 for such a detailed, thoughtful answer to a question that is basically hopeless. :)

Comment: it might be possible to train an AI on a list of well-formatted addresses (like a phone book) and then get it to make sense of this essentially-junk file.  it's probably easier (and with a more certain result) to just edit the file and fix it. or pay someone to do it.

Comment: I imagine it is possible with AI. And every smart business person in the world would hire some dude to do it manually, instead. ;)

Comment: at first, I thank cas and B Layer for such quick response. The data was provided by one of my friend who worked on it for months to gether this much information (address) from various resources and very hopeful while giving it to me (thought being a linux enthusiast). I too agree that the data was purely raw and without any specific pattern but I must believe that there are many tasks which seem difficult and provide a different taste of satisfaction when we do it successfuly. I have performed the following operations on this file to get result upto maximum of what I can.

Comment: **At first I made a copy of this file**
`cp address-list.csv file.csv`

**Then replaced all non-alphanumeric characters with space within file using command**
`sed -i "s/[^A-Z,^0-9]/ /Ig" file.csv`

**Then removed all leading and trailing spaces**
`sed -i "s/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//" file.csv`

**Then replaced instances of multiple spaces to single space**
`sed -i "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" file.csv`

**Now, I selected first 8 field space delemited and redirected to a new file called _file2.csv_**
`cat file.csv | cut -d" " -f1-8 > file2.csv`

Comment: **Now I again removed leading and trailing spaces for the sake of becoming more errorless**
`sed -i "s/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//" file2.csv`

**Then, I replaced all instances of _space_ with _.*_ to use this file as input for _grep_ command using _AND_ condition**
`sed -i 's/ /\.\*/Ig' file2.csv`

**I used this to identify duplicate address in my new file _file2.csv_**
`cat file2.csv | sort | uniq -id | sort -n > dupli-add.txt`

Here we have list of duplicate addresses (one for each group) based on the comparison of first 8 field delemited by _space_.

Comment: **Replace all instances of _space_ with _.*_ in _dupli-add.txt_**
`sed -i 's/ /\.\*/Ig' dupli-add.txt`

**Now we can search the addresses from _dupli-add.txt_ into the original address file _address.csv_ and redirect the output for each duplicate address separately**
`mkdir -p new-dupli-folder`
**then**
`for addr in $(cat dupli-add.txt); do grep -i "$addr" address-list.csv > new-dupli-folder/"$addr".csv; done`

**Thats all**